# Several species of birds which or in which...?

Tags: grammar

There are several species of birds { which / in which} the parents will ignore their own offspring if they are put outside their nest.

Which one of the two in the bracket is correct? Or, I think, the third possibility is that There are......birds whose parents will ignore ....   Could you help me clarify it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use *in which*. The reason why you should use *in which* instead of simply saying *which* is that *species* scientifically is defined as a group of living organisms consisting of similar individuals capable of exchanging genes or interbreeding and since a species is nothing more than a group, whatever happens inside a group among its members takes place in or within that group (*in* and *within* are the operative words here):

> There are several species of birds **in which** (within the species) the parents will ignore their own offspring if they are put outside their nest.

Another similar example with regard to biology that hopefully will drive the point home:

> Are there species of animals **in which** males give birth?

Substitute *species* with *groups* and you will see that the sentence still makes perfect sense. Whereas leaving out *in* would render it incoherent.

Comment: I fully agree with this answer, but it does not explain why the answer is correct.